# how can i get things from the chrome console into a python list?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with python which includes selenium and chrome driver. Now i want to get things from the chrome console into a list in python (look at the picture)
So i want to get all the numbers in front of "data-form-field-value=" into a list like:
314214536204070
314214536204075
314214536204080
How can i do it?

Chrome console insight:

[image: chrome console insight]

i already tried it but i couldnt find anything in the internet which could helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 buttons = driver.ind_elements_by_tag_name("button")
 lst = [ button.get_attribute("data-form-field-value") for button in buttons]
```

now lst will have the value you need